# Problem with: clone object prior drag & drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, clone

To keep the original element at its position, I would like to clone it and drag the cloned one. It works so far. But if I do a "doubleclick" (prior to drag) on the element to clone, I get two cloned objects and the drop inserts two elements instead of one. Can someone help me to fix that. I tried to work with an additional eventlistener for mouseup. I didn´t find a solution. I guess its simple, but at the moment I don´t see it... thanks for any help!

Here is a reduced part of my entire code:

```
let basicElement = document.getElementById('basicElement');
basicElement.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

// press element...
function mousedown(e){
  console.log('mouse down');
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  // clone element
  let elementToDrag = basicElement.cloneNode(true);
  elementToDrag.id = new Date().getMilliseconds();

  // get target
  let divTarget = getElementById('divTarget');

  // add event listener for drag and drop
  basicElement.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
  basicElement.addEventListener('dragend', dragend);

  divTarget.addEventListener('dragover', dragover);
  divTarget.addEventListener('drop', drop);
  
  function dragstart(e){
    console.log('drag start');
    basicElement.classList.add('dragging');
  }

  function dragover(e){
    console.log('drag over');
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function drop(e){
    console.log('drop');
    divTarget.appendChild(panelToDrag);
  
  }

  function dragend(e){
    console.log('drag end');

    basicElement.classList.remove('dragging');

    basicElement.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
    basicElement.removeEventListener('dragend', dragend);
    divTarget.removeEventListener('dragover', dragover);
    divTarget.removeEventListener('drop', drop);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, it didnt work in my code. But you gave me the hint to the following solution:

```
let basicElement = document.getElementById('basicElement');
basicElement.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
// new flag
let isDragging = false;

// press element...
function mousedown(e){
  console.log('mouse down');
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Stop cloning if we have click at it once
  if(isDragging == false) {
    // clone element
    let elementToDrag = basicElement.cloneNode(true);
    elementToDrag.id = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    isDragging = true;
  } else {
    if (isDragging){
      console.log(isDragging);
      return;
    }
  }

  
  

  // get target
  let divTarget = getElementById('divTarget');

  // add event listener for drag and drop
  basicElement.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
  basicElement.addEventListener('dragend', dragend);

  divTarget.addEventListener('dragover', dragover);
  divTarget.addEventListener('drop', drop);
  
  function dragstart(e){
    console.log('drag start');
    // Reset isDragging if drag starts
    isDragging = false;
    basicElement.classList.add('dragging');
  }

  function dragover(e){
    console.log('drag over');
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function drop(e){
    console.log('drop');
    divTarget.appendChild(panelToDrag);
  }

  function dragend(e){
    console.log('drag end');

    basicElement.classList.remove('dragging');

    basicElement.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
    basicElement.removeEventListener('dragend', dragend);
    divTarget.removeEventListener('dragover', dragover);
    divTarget.removeEventListener('drop', drop);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mousedown` will create a cloned element, simply clicking at the `basicElement` will create more cloned elements, which will all be ready to be dropped. `mousedown` also creates an event listener for dropping with each cloned element.

A simple way to make this work will be adding a flag.

```
let basicElement = document.getElementById('basicElement');
basicElement.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
// new flag
let isDragging = false;

// press element...
function mousedown(e){
  console.log('mouse down');
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Stop cloning if we have click at it once
  if(isDragging) {
     return;
  }
  
  // clone element
  let elementToDrag = basicElement.cloneNode(true);
  elementToDrag.id = new Date().getMilliseconds();

  // get target
  let divTarget = getElementById('divTarget');

  // add event listener for drag and drop
  basicElement.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
  basicElement.addEventListener('dragend', dragend);

  divTarget.addEventListener('dragover', dragover);
  divTarget.addEventListener('drop', drop);
  
  function dragstart(e){
    console.log('drag start');
    basicElement.classList.add('dragging');
  }

  function dragover(e){
    console.log('drag over');
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function drop(e){
    console.log('drop');
    divTarget.appendChild(panelToDrag);
    // Reset isDragging once it's over
    isDragging = false;
  }

  function dragend(e){
    console.log('drag end');

    basicElement.classList.remove('dragging');

    basicElement.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
    basicElement.removeEventListener('dragend', dragend);
    divTarget.removeEventListener('dragover', dragover);
    divTarget.removeEventListener('drop', drop);
  }
}
```

This fixes the issue, but this only works with one target and one origin. If it's many to many, you need to think about registering ids instead of using a boolean flag.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Have changed your code - please see below

Comment: @Harald Looks good, glad you solved it. If you don't mind adding a small summary of explanation to help others that comes across it.